# How can I use XAML triggers to respond to RoutedCommands?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, eventtrigger

I'm trying to fire a `TriggerAction` in response to a `RoutedCommand` passing through a control which doesn't otherwise handle it. The problem is that as far as I can tell there is no such thing as "`CommandTrigger`".

This is the closest I've come to the functionality I want:

```
<MyControl.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger xmlns:in="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Input;assembly=PresentationCore"
                RoutedEvent="in:CommandManager.PreviewExecuted">
    <SoundPlayerAction Source="foo"/>
  </EventTrigger>
</ui:Sidebar.Triggers>
```

The sound is played whenever a command passes though `MyControl`, but it's not possible to specify *which* command to fire in response to. So close...

This wouldn't be such a problem if it weren't for the non-extensibility of the Trigger/Action system. [According to someone on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/3b4ffee0-434d-41c2-aa8f-07a2c2efa936/#7b6d9293-9778-4612-9e03-7f58338e6ff6) the necessary methods and constructors are `internal`.

**Things I have tried:**

- I am aware of the extensible Blend class [`System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726552%28v=expression.40%29.aspx), and in fact I've already created my own custom class based on it which does exactly what I want. Unfortunately none of that is an option as my target environment doesn't implement it.
- I am also aware that it would be trivial to add a `CommandBinding` to the control and avoid setting `e.Handled = true`, but the whole point of this exercise is to avoid code-behind.

Comment: The name "Blend Trigger" is a historical relic and was created to distinguish `*.Interactivity.Trigger` from the "regular" trigger (the one you can put in `DataTemplate.Triggers` or `ControlTemplate.Triggers`). In reality, to use `*.Interactivity.Trigger` you just need a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` which is part of .NET 4.5 (and, IIRC, .NET 4.0). Do you have something preventing you from referencing this DLL?

Comment: My target environment doesn't implement it. Yes, I've checked. :)

Comment: Can you reference the DLL?